# Is there a possibility of data corruption/lost when inserting large blob data from one table to another table in the same database?

Tags: oracle, corruption

I am trying to determine if data corruption/lost is possible when moving large data from one table to another in the same schema.

I am new to programming and database is not my forte. Anyway I've tried some sql query to transfer data and check differences but I want to hear from database dev experts to confirm.

I used

```
INSERT INTO table_name2
SELECT *
FROM table_name1;
```

query to transfer data from one table to another.

Comment: How are you moving the data, and why do you think loss/corruption might be possible - have you experienced a problem? If so give details, including the commands run, what happened, and the version and patch level of the database and any tools involved. (If there is any genuine loss/corruption and it isn't down to a mistake in your method, that would probably be an issue for Oracle Support.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to determine if data corruption/lost is possible when moving large data from one table to another in the same schema.

Whilst it is possible for this to occur, it is very, *very* unlikely.

Insert should store exactly the same data as the select feeds to it.

That data is initially written to the redo log - any corruption at that point should kill the database stone dead.

Some time later, the data is written to the DataFiles.
Any corruption at that point may not be noticed!  Oracle only checks the integrity of a data block when it *reads* it from disk, not when writing it.  However, you should have sufficient redundancy built into your system - regular backups and, possibly, a standby database - to handle this but, again, it's very unlikely.

If you *are* seeing data corruption when doing this, then either there's a Data Type conversion involved that you're not mentioning or something is *very* wrong with your database.  Copying data around inside the database should be like breathing - you really shouldn't have to think about it.